# Help me with this ActiveRecord Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I was deploying my application in staging and it use to work properly. But in the recent deployment I am getting a crazy error like this,

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_user_name' for #<Class:0xb6dd8388>):
  app/models/user.rb:49:in `find_or_create_account'
  app/models/user.rb:24:in `authenticate'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:42:in `login'
  /usr/website/coachportal/current/public/dispatch.fcgi:24
```

For which the line in `user.rb` reads this.

```
.......
  def find_or_create_account(ldap_entry = nil)
    acc = Account.find_or_initialize_by_user_name(self.user_name)
    acc_attrs = {}
.........
```

Here `Account` is an ActiveRecord Model, but I am getting an error that relates to `Class:0xb6dd8388` Someone please help me!!

Thanks.

Comment: does the method exists in class Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your database schema: the reason of such an error could be the absence of `user_name` column in the `accounts` table.

Comment: Someone have corrupted the account table in the system which messed up all the columns.. Thanks dude.. you saved my day!